# Linear Algebra with Reflection

Tags: linear-algebra

Point P(-2,5) is reflected on the line y=2x/5. How do you find the coordinates of P using linear algebra? P(-2,5) needs to be mapped across the x axis without using the difference formula

Comment: @RushabhMehta It is not a duplicate