# Linear Algebra with Reflection Across Axis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reflection

Point $P(-2,5)$ is reflected on the line $y=\frac{2}{5}x$. How do you find the coordinates of the reflection using linear algebra and not the distance formula?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Algebra with Reflection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978580/linear-algebra-with-reflection)

Comment: Rotate, reflect across the $x$-axis, rotate back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector representing the slope of the line is $\overrightarrow{m}=(run,rise)=(5,2)$. The vector representing the point is $\overrightarrow{P}=(-2,5)$

Notice that $\overrightarrow{P}$ is perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{m}$, so the vector $\overrightarrow{P}$ gives us the distance from $P$ to the line.

In particular, reflection of the point P is given by $$-\overrightarrow{P}=(2,-5)$$

(draw the picture and you will see why this works)

Comment: That would be a reflection, but I'm not sure how you reflect it over the line y=2/5x

Comment: Because the 2 vectors I mention are perpendicular, it is the reflection over the line.  Please draw the picture and you should see it